# Manipulate URL parameters with map() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to map through an array so i can get all the notes pushed in an array **params.createdNotes** can i map inside the variable **sortNotes** so i can have a url like below :

**/api/35678&page=1&notes[]=2&notes[]=4&notes[]=5**

```
params.createdNotes = [2, 4, 5]

instance.fetchNotes = (params) => {
    let sortNotes =  (params.createdNotes.length === 0) ? '' : '&notes[]='+params.createdNotes;
    return  instance.get(
        '/api/'+params.section+'&page='+params.currentPage+sortNotes
    )
}
```

Comment: I suggest using the built-in [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API so you don't have to fiddle with (and probably mess up) creating query strings yourself.

Comment: If you want an answer, you have to tell us what exactly `params` is. It looks like `params.section` starts with a `?`; otherwise, you wouldn't be creating a querystring.

Comment: section, currentPage and createdNotes are states, i gave the example of the array createdNotes because thats where i am having trouble i don't know how tu use map() to get multiple &notes[]=x in my url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript modify url parameter array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039033/javascript-modify-url-parameter-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding parameters to URL, putting array in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664019/adding-parameters-to-url-putting-array-in-query-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built-in [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) API to take care of creating a valid querystring first. Then when we're done, call `toString` to get the resulting querystring.

```js
const createdNotes = [2, 4, 5];

const params = new URLSearchParams();

createdNotes.forEach((note) => params.append("note[]", note));

console.log(params.toString());
```

In the context of your code:

```js
instance.fetchNotes = (params) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams();

  params.set("section", params.section); // or whatever
  params.set("page", params.currentPage);

  // append params
  params.createdNotes.forEach((note) => params.append("notes[]", note));

  return instance.get(
    "/api/?" + params.toString() // now we're done, turn into querystring
  );
};
```

Comment: This answer would be better suited on the duplicate

Comment: params.toString() returns %5B%5D instead of [] and %26 instead of &

Comment: @Elichy `%5B%5D` is explainable because that's the URI encoding of `[]`, but why are you using `&`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think the target question is suitable. I think a better one would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664019/adding-parameters-to-url-putting-array-in-query-string

Comment: i am using & because of the structure of api, i might have for ex note[]=4&note[]=5&note[]=5

Comment: @Elichy You don't need `&`. `URLSearchParams` will handle creating the final query string for you. Are you even using `URLSearchParams` (like my answer uses)?